# Trouble using powershell output as a variable in batch file

Tags: windows, powershell, batch, command, prompt

I can manually run this command from a Windows Command Prompt:

```
powershell (new-timespan -start 01/01/2000 -end (get-date)).days % 14
```

And it returns a number from 0 to 13. I want to use this result in a batch file, but this line gives an error back:

```
for /f %%i in ('powershell (new-timespan -start 01/01/2000 -end (get-date)).days % 14') do set doc=%%i
```

The error:

> ).days was unexpected at this time.

I suspect I need to add more quotes, double quotes, apostrophes and brackets but I've tried every possible combination and can't get it to work. I think maybe some ^^s are needed too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `FOR` command you need escape not only the parenthesis, but the mod (percent) as well. The parens are escaped with `^`, the percent by `%`. Note that this will only work within a batch file, not the command line.

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('powershell ^(new-timespan -start 01/01/2000 -end ^(get-date^)^).days %% 14') DO (
    SET doc=%%i
)

ECHO %doc%
```